# Ionic3 while setting iframe to full screen page reloads

Tags: typescript, iframe, ionic-framework, fullscreen

In my application (android) I have iframes with video (youtube and vimeo). When I had ionic version 2 then I could set iframe to fullscreen but after updating application to ionic 3 it is not working. When I click fullscreen button then application page reloads and full screen disappears. Has anyone similar problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs for fullscreen](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-full-screen/)? Also you might want to follow some [Migration guide](https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-an-ionic-2-project-to-ionic-3).

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

in HTML file add..

```
<iframe class= 'webPage' name= "eventsPage" [src]="url" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

and in CSS file add..

```
ion-content div.scroll{
   height: 90%; 
}

.webPage{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: transparent;
   padding: 1rem;
}
```

hope this will help you